# How to callback a function in tableView's Class from tableViewCell's Class

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, callback

I'm having a TableView. In that tableView, I custom it's cells 
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qq4lz.png)

In this cell I have 2 part. An Image and an TextField.
It's look like facebook's post status. When I click to Image, I want to open a new ViewController and the same for TextField

But I have a problem that I can't call segue from my cell's class file.

1. Are there any way that I can call a function in `TableViewController's class` from `TableViewCell's class` ?

I know that I can use `delegate` but I don't like this way a lot, because if I do this way I have to set a lot of `delegate` in my project.

2. Are there any better way to present a new ViewController directly from `TableViewCell's class`

Comment: i have idea to you a way you able use "block(Objective-c)" or "closure(Swift)" to call back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a delegate is a very good way to solve your problem.

If you don't like that solution then you could design a table view cell that has a closure property set by the view controller, and invokes that closure when the button is pressed.

### EDIT:

Another alternative is to leave the button action empty in your custom cell, but still connect up outlets to the buttons.

Then in your `cellForRow(at:)` method, install an IBAction that has your view controller as the target. (Credit to @SoanSani, who's answer is below)

In that IBAction method, you can use the coordinates of the button to figure out the indexPath of the cell hat contains the button that was tapped.

I've created an extension to UITableView that lets you figure out the cell that contains any view. The code is below:

```
import UIKit

public extension UITableView {
  
  /**
  This method returns the indexPath of the cell that contains the specified view
   
   - Parameter view: The view to find.
   
   - Returns: The indexPath of the cell containing the view, or nil if it can't be found
   
  */
  
  func indexPathForView(_ view: UIView) -> IndexPath? {
    let origin = view.bounds.origin
    let viewOrigin = self.convert(origin, from: view)
    let indexPath = self.indexPathForRow(at: viewOrigin)
    return indexPath
  }
}
```

Comment: So... I think delegate still is the best way to callback. Btw: your suggestion is very cool

Answer (score 0):

You can use delegates, but if you dont want to use delegates

while setting up the cell add target to your button tableViewController class and then you can receive all events in tableview class rather than cell class.

But this would require to add tags which you can use to differentiate which button in cell was clicked

Objective C Code

```
   [OkBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(okButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Swift Code

```
   OkBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.okButtonTapped), for: .TouchUpInside)
```

Comment: Your suggestion of installing an action from the view controller in the button is a good alternative, but I don't like using tags to figure out the cell's indexPath. See my answer for a better way to do that.